# validating the origin header in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, csrf, csrf-protection

In the OWASP CSRF guidelines (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) their number one "no brainer" recommendation for CSRF protection is to validate that the origin header matches the current request origin.

However, I've noticed ASP.NET MVC 4.0 doesn't seem to do this by default (note: I haven't tested Web API yet; this is just plain MVC controllers)

Is there a good reason this isn't enabled by default? Is there a built-in feature I can simply just turn on or do I have to roll-my-own? if I do implement origin checking, are there any caveats I might have missed?

I appreciate that you can't trust headers if the browser has been compromised, but OWASP point out (quite reasonably IMO) that if the attacker has already compromised the browser, they're unlikely to need a CSRF attack.

I haven't included sample code here, but basically I just built two simple web sites, one of which contains a form and the other posts to that form.

**Edit:** on the basis of this: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Origin, I have concluded that valid AJAX requests should always contain a valid origin header. FWIW here's the code I intend to use to validate said header for requests which do not allow CORS (which for my application is all AJAX requests)

```
string origin = Request.Headers["Origin"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(origin))
{
    throw new Exception("origin is not specified");
}
string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
if (!url.StartsWith(origin))
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("invalid request origin {0} for request url {1}", origin, url));
}
```

Comment: Did you google for CSRF and MVC? First hit pretty much says it all: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: @martennis yes of course I'm aware of the built-in features to generate and validate anti-forgery tokens. However, in the interests of defense-in-depth, OWASP recommends this is used in conjunction with validating the origin header, and it's the latter that I'm asking about here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get that from the question.
One reason why CSRF and CORS (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing) are seperate, is because it is perfectly valid for a website to post a form to a different website, if it has a valid token. It's up to your security requirement weither or not to enforce CORS (and to what extend).